# RadGrid and Internet Explorer layout issues

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, gridview, telerik, radgrid

I was wondering why the hell this is happening to my RadGrid by Telerik, it has a not too complex details table. On Firefox it works pretty well, Chrome too. But on IE there are a lot of issues, it is not showing the insert button (on details grid), and if I click on Edit the layout does not change, well here are the screenshots:

on Firefox: [image: Firefox]

on IE: [image: IE]

If anyone knows why this is happening, please reply.

Thanks

This is the RadGrid code on ASPX page:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gridDocumentos" runat="server" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="0" 
    AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True"
            AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" 
    DataSourceID="DocumentosDataSource" GridLines="None" Culture="pt-BR" 
    Skin="Metro" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1080px" 
                             onitemdatabound="gridDocumentos_ItemDataBound" 
                             oniteminserted="gridDocumentos_ItemInserted" 
                             OnItemCommand="gridDocumentos_ItemCommand" 
        onitemupdated="gridDocumentos_ItemUpdated" 
        onitemcreated="gridDocumentos_ItemCreated" 
        onupdatecommand="gridDocumentos_UpdateCommand" >
            <exportsettings>
                <pdf pagewidth="">
                </pdf>
            </exportsettings>
            <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True">
            </ClientSettings>
            <mastertableview autogeneratecolumns="False" datakeynames="DOC_Id" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"  
            AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
    datasourceid="DocumentosDataSource" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true"
                NoDetailRecordsText="Não revisões desse documento para mostrar.">
                <EditFormSettings> 
                        <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" InsertText="Adicionar" CancelText="Cancelar" UpdateText="Atualizar" > 
                        </EditColumn> 
                      </EditFormSettings> 
                <detailtables>
                    <telerik:GridTableView  runat="server"  ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="REV_Id" DataSourceID="DocumentosDetailsDataSource" 
                        AllowAutomaticInserts="True" CommandItemDisplay="Bottom" InsertCommand="gridDocumentos_InsertCommand"
                        NoMasterRecordsText="Não há documentos para mostrar." >

                        <ParentTableRelation>
                            <telerik:GridRelationFields DetailKeyField="FK_DOC_Id" 
                                MasterKeyField="DOC_Id" />
                        </ParentTableRelation>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_Id" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_Id column" SortExpression="REV_Id" 
                                UniqueName="REV_Id" Display="false" ReadOnly="True" DataType="System.Int32">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="FK_DOC_Id" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter FK_DOC_Id column" SortExpression="FK_DOC_Id" 
                                UniqueName="FK_DOC_Id" Display="false" DataType="System.Int32">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_NomeArquivo" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_NomeArquivo column" SortExpression="REV_NomeArquivo" 
                                UniqueName="REV_NomeArquivo" HeaderText="Nome do arquivo" Visible ="false" >
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_Codigo" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_Codigo column" HeaderText="Código da Revisão" 
                                SortExpression="REV_Codigo" UniqueName="REV_Codigo">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_Descr" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_Descr column" HeaderText="Descrição" 
                                SortExpression="REV_Descr" UniqueName="REV_Descr">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_Tipo" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_Tipo column" HeaderText="Tipo" 
                                SortExpression="REV_Tipo" UniqueName="REV_Tipo" >
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_Tamanho" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_Tamanho column" HeaderText="Tamanho" 
                                SortExpression="REV_Tamanho" UniqueName="REV_Tamanho" >
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="REV_DataEnvio" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter REV_DataEnvio column" HeaderText="Data de envio" 
                                SortExpression="REV_DataEnvio" UniqueName="REV_DataEnvio" ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName_EnviadoPor" 
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter UserName_EnviadoPor column" 
                                HeaderText="Revisão enviada por:" UniqueName="UserName_EnviadoPor" ReadOnly="true">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn
                                FilterControlAltText="Filter Download column" Text="Download" 
                                UniqueName="Download" HeaderText="Download">
                            </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>

                             <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Sobrescrever versão" 
                                UniqueName="TemplateColumn1" Visible ="false">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate> 
</ItemTemplate>  
             <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload2" 
              MultipleFileSelection=Disabled MaxFileInputsCount="1" HttpHandlerUrl="~/Pages/UploadHandler.ashx"
              TemporaryFileExpiration="30"
              Culture="pt-BR" Height="24px" Width="330px"   >
              <Localization Cancel="Cancelar" DropZone="Arraste arquivos para cá" 
                  Remove="Remover" Select="Selecionar" />
                                           </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>

                                       <telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" 
                 ID="RadProgressArea2" Culture="pt-BR" 
              Skin="WebBlue" Language="pt-BR" Width="299px" >
<Localization Uploaded="Enviado" Cancel="Cancelar" CurrentFileName="Enviando arquivo:" 
                  ElapsedTime="Tempo decorrido:" EstimatedTime="Tempo estimado:" 
                  TotalFiles="Arquivos:" TransferSpeed="Velocidade" 
                  UploadedFiles="Arquivos Enviados:"></Localization>
          </telerik:RadProgressArea>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                            <telerik:GridButtonColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" 
                                UniqueName="column">
                            </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Enviar nova revisão" 
                                UniqueName="TemplateColumn2" Visible ="false">
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadProgressArea runat="server" 
                 ID="RadProgressArea3" Culture="pt-BR" 
              Skin="WebBlue" Language="pt-BR" Width="299px" >
<Localization Uploaded="Enviado" Cancel="Cancelar" CurrentFileName="Enviando arquivo:" 
                  ElapsedTime="Tempo decorrido:" EstimatedTime="Tempo estimado:" 
                  TotalFiles="Arquivos:" TransferSpeed="Velocidade" 
                  UploadedFiles="Arquivos Enviados:"></Localization>
          </telerik:RadProgressArea>
                            <telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload3" 
              MultipleFileSelection=Disabled MaxFileInputsCount="1" HttpHandlerUrl="~/Pages/UploadHandler.ashx"
              TemporaryFileExpiration="30"
              Culture="pt-BR" Height="24px" Width="330px"   > <Localization Select="Selecionar" Cancel = "Cancelar" Remove = "Remover" />
                                           </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>                                        
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </telerik:GridTableView>
                </detailtables>
                <rowindicatorcolumn visible="False">
                </rowindicatorcolumn>
                <ExpandCollapseColumn Created="True">
                </ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOC_Id" DataType="System.Int32" 
                        HeaderText="DOC_Id" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="DOC_Id" UniqueName="DOC_Id" Visible="False" >
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOC_Titulo" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DOC_Titulo column" HeaderText="Título" 
                        SortExpression="DOC_Titulo" UniqueName="DOC_Titulo">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOC_Descr" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DOC_Descr column" HeaderText="Descrição" 
                        UniqueName="DOC_Descr">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOC_Codigo" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DOC_Codigo column" HeaderText="Código" 
                        SortExpression="DOC_Codigo" UniqueName="DOC_Codigo">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                     <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="FormatoDataSource" Visible ="false"
                    ListTextField="FOR_Descr" ListValueField="FOR_Id" DataField="FK_FOR_Id" UniqueName="FK_FOR_Id" HeaderText="Formato" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                    <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="SituacaoDataSource"
                    ListTextField="SIT_Descr" ListValueField="SIT_Id" DataField="FK_SIT_Id" UniqueName="FK_SIT_Id" HeaderText="Situação" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                    <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="MidiaDataSource"
                    ListTextField="MID_Descr" ListValueField="MID_Id" DataField="FK_MID_Id" UniqueName="FK_MID_Id"  HeaderText="Mídia" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                     <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="SistemaDataSource"
                    ListTextField="SIS_Descr" ListValueField="SIS_Id" DataField="FK_SIS_Id" UniqueName="FK_SIS_Id"  HeaderText="Sistema" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                    <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="SubSistemaDataSource" Visible ="false"
                    ListTextField="SUB_Descr" ListValueField="SUB_Id" DataField="FK_SUB_Id" UniqueName="FK_SUB_Id"  HeaderText="SubSistema" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                     <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="CategoriaDataSource" Visible="false"
                    ListTextField="CAT_Descr" ListValueField="CAT_Id" DataField="FK_CAT_Id" UniqueName="FK_CAT_Id"  HeaderText="Categoria" >
                    </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>

                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Mudar o documento de nó" 
                                UniqueName="TemplateChangeNode" Visible ="false">
                        <EditItemTemplate>

                    <telerik:RadDropDownTree ID="RadDropDownTree1" runat="server">
                    </telerik:RadDropDownTree>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DOC_CriadoEm" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DOC_CriadoEm column" HeaderText="Criado em" ReadOnly="true"
                        UniqueName="DOC_CriadoEm">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="UserName" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter UserName column" 
                        HeaderText="Documendo criado por" UniqueName="UserName"  ReadOnly="true">
                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>


                    <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn DataField="DOC_ASerRecebido" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter DOC_ASerRecebido column" 
                        HeaderText="A ser recebido?" UniqueName="DOC_ASerRecebido"  ReadOnly="true">
                    </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>

                </Columns>
            </mastertableview>
        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: What IE version are you using? And have you checked what browser mode it is using? (if it's quirks mode or compatibility mode, then that'll be your problem right there)

Comment: @Spudley I'm using version 10, and on normal mode (no compatibility). I've tested on other computers and the problem persists.